# Mismatch between RSpec tests and console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a setter method in Rails that prints out a lastname (debug info):

```
def password=(new_password)

    logger.info 'DEBUG: self.lastname: ' + self.lastname

    self.password_hash = SCrypt::Password.create(new_password, :key_len => 512, :salt_size => 32)


end
```

If I use a console (either Development or Test env) I get:

```
2.0.0p0 :001 > u = User.new
 => #<User uuid: nil, account_id: nil, username_id: nil, password_hash: "", can_login: true, firstname: "", lastname: "", phone: "", mobile: "", fax: "", role: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.0.0p0 :002 > u.lastname = "some lastname"
 => "some lastname"
2.0.0p0 :003 > u.password = "test"
DEBUG: self.lastname: some lastname
=> "test"
```

However when I run the RSpec test and tail the log/test.log and grep for DEBUG I simply get:

```
DEBUG: self.lastname:
```

As if the lastname isn't accessible in the RSpec test (it's a RSpec test for the user model). Is it a bug in RSpec or what am I doing wrong here?

The factory definition is:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    account
    current_username 'user@domain.com'
    password 'iTho6chi'
    can_login true
    firstname 'John'
    lastname 'Doe'
    phone '555-1234'
    mobile '555-4321'
    fax '555-4321'
  end
end
```

and:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  it 'should create a new user using the FactoryGirl registration of user' do

    FactoryGirl.create(:user).should be_valid

  end

end
```

Gives:

```
Finished in 0.376 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

and the test.log file gives:

```
DEBUG: self.lastname:
```

(the lastname is not unset anywhere and it's required to be set in the model, so it is set since the test passes)

Comment: Can we see the test in question? Maybe you're not creating a lastname, or you're resetting it to blank somewhere, or you're using a factory that doesn't set it, etc.

Comment: Added FactoryGirl info and RSpec test run data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this has to do with the order you are defining things in FactoryGirl. You set the password before you set the last name, so at the point where it calls your `password=` method, the `lastname` attribute is nil.

If you change the order, you'll see the expected debug information.